# Apache HTTP-Basic Auth not working

Tags: apache-2.2, http-basic-authentication

I have a really simple authorization configuration, but I'm getting a weird message rather than a user/password field when I try to access the page.

Here's my `.htaccess` file:

```
AuthType basic
AuthName "No Way"
AuthUserFile /path/to/auth/file.password
Require valid-user
```

Here's what I'm seeing in my browser:

[image]

The problem is, I haven't even had the opportunity to offer my credentials.

## EDIT

It seems that the problem is caused by using a different DNS name. I'm running a dynamic DNS for my domain name and if I use another domain which forwards to the first name, it doesn't work. If I use the original domain name, it works.

IE:

```
me.dyndns.org/secure - Works
me.myserver.org/secure - Doesn't work.
```

It seems that a simple `ping` of `me.myserver.org` points to a GoDaddy address, so I'm not even sure how it's forwarding to my server at all. A `ping` of `me.dyndns.org` returns the right IP, though. How can I set up domain forwarding to have the domain map to the IP address of the `dyndns` domain?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Firefox, you should clear cache and active logins or try with another web browser.

Comment: I've isolated the problem down a bit further, it has to do with DNS issues, it would seem. Please see the question edit.